# Using textures with Three.js and PLY file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the ascii ply file loading fine now, but it has a texture and I can not seem to get it to load not matter how I configure things.

```
    cameraMain = new THREE.Camera(8, MainWidth / MainHeight, 1, 10000);
sceneMain = new THREE.Scene();
ambientLightMain = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x202020);
directionalLightMainRight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
directionalLightMainLeft = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
pointLightMain = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.3);

directionalLightMainRight.position.x = dlpx;
directionalLightMainRight.position.y = dlpy;
directionalLightMainRight.position.z = dlpz;
directionalLightMainRight.position.normalize();

directionalLightMainLeft.position.x = -dlpx;
directionalLightMainLeft.position.y = dlpy;
directionalLightMainLeft.position.z = dlpz;
directionalLightMainLeft.position.normalize();  

pointLightMain.position.x = plpx;
pointLightMain.position.y = plpy;
pointLightMain.position.z = plpz;

sceneMain.addLight(ambientLightMain);
sceneMain.addLight(directionalLightMainRight);
sceneMain.addLight(directionalLightMainLeft);
sceneMain.addLight(pointLightMain);

rendererMain = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('3D/'+ mainURL +'.jpg', {}, function() {
    rendererMain.render(sceneMain);
});

rendererMain.domElement.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
rendererMain.setSize(MainWidth, MainHeight);
rendererMain.domElement.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onRendererMainScroll, false);
rendererMain.domElement.addEventListener('mousewheel', onRendererMainScroll, false);
rendererMain.domElement.addEventListener('dblclick', onRendererMainDblClick, false);
rendererMain.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onRendererMainMouseDown, false);

$("#viewerMain").append(rendererMain.domElement);

window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
```

That chunk of code initializes the model. Some of it is not needed for question purposes, it has code for zooming, rotating, etc. I know there is another line, I have it commented out but for some reason it wont show here so I will do it separately.

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
```

That line is after the loadTexture code.

The rest of it is loaded with a loadPly function

```
        var geometryMain = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (i in event.data.content[0])
      geometryMain.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(event.data.content[0][i][0], event.data.content[0][i][1], event.data.content[0][i][2])));
    for (i in event.data.content[1])
      geometryMain.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(event.data.content[1][i][0], event.data.content[1][i][1], event.data.content[1][i][2]));
    geometryMain.computeCentroids();
    geometryMain.computeFaceNormals();
    mainModel = new THREE.Mesh(geometryMain, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, shading:THREE.FlatShading}));
    sceneMain.addObject(mainModel);
    mainModel.overdraw = true;
    mainModel.doubleSided = true;
```

I have tried tweaking the THREE.mesh() section to include the material but it breaks everything. I have tried just adding the map:material to the MeshLambertMaterial, also a no go. Anyone have any insight? Sorry if this is over complicated but i am far from knowing this enough to be efficient yet.

If I add

```
map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('3D/'+ mainURL +'.jpg')
```

to the THREE.Mesh() line, I get

> .WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to display a texture on an object, it needs texture coordinates. You only seem to add vertices and faces to the geometry. Looking at `THREE.PLYLoader` sources, it doesn't seem to support loading the texture coords. (Although I'm not sure if you use that loader as it should already return a ready `Geometry` instance instead of requiring you to construct arrays manually)

Comment: I dont use it, it was not available when this was first written, so another library is being used. As for the response, textures are added via an image file (JPG, GIF), not a coordinate file (PLY), so i am not sure what you mean?

Comment: I'm saying a texture (image) is not enough. In order to map it to the surface of the object you additionally need to supply texture coordinates (also known as UV coordinates). In general, each vertex has an added Vector2 with its components ranging from 0 to 1. These "u" and "v" coordinates tell which part of the texture image is mapped to the vertex in question. E.g. an UV of (0.5, 0.5) would mean the middle of the texture is put into this particular vertex.

Comment: Can you email me so i can ask you a question about this? Easier than back and forth here which i dont think they like, austinb AT motionview3d DOT com

Comment: @AustinBest: If my answer is not clear or correct, feel free to ask for clarification here in the comments, so I can make my contribution acceptable for you. If you have a question unrelated to the original "Using textures with Three.js and PLY file" (E.g. "What is UV mapping?" or "How can I add texture coordinates to a PLY file?"), ask a new question (feel free to point me there). I prefer this to remain public so others can benefit and contribute. If I were someone with a similar problem, I'd hate to find this only to discover some essential piece was moved to a private email discussion.

Comment: I would post the solution once figured out. I also posted on github https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3382 as i do not see anything in the examples that do more than link the ply & texture image. There is not much in terms of documentation and i can not find any working examples.

Comment: Also an FYI, the PLY file has the UV coordinates in it.

Comment: http://prv.webhop.net/development/3D/examples/a.html with that you can see the texture file, you can see the ply, you can see the UV points. Maybe that will help someone to tell me what i am doing wrong in calling it? Thanks.

Comment: @AustinBest: Looking at the PLY loader sources, it does not support loading the UVs. It only adds vertex and face information to the `Geometry` it creates. Look into some other loaders to see how it can be implemented.

Comment: I use the supplied ply loader with three.js, but thank you for the definitive answer. Will try the OBJ loader or other.

Answer (score 1):

Use THREE.MeshNormalMaterial. It shows texture when you use MeshNormalMaterial.

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you for the assist on this 6 year old post.