# Three.js ply colorless (all black)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to load my ply file using Three.js. It has worked but I almost don't see any colors. There are some glimpses here and there, but it's mostly black (the first image below).  The image opens properly (with colors) in MeshLab (the second image below). I have tried `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors` (as suggested in [Three.js - ply files - why colorless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425761/three-js-ply-files-why-colorless)) and `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors` but nothing seemed to help. I am a three.js newbie, so please tell me what am I doing wrong.

[image: Three.js]
[image: MeshLab]

and my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Icon 7</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">

  <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/PLYLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>

  <script>

    // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer as global variables.
    var scene, camera, renderer;

    init();
    animate();

    // Sets up the scene.
    function init() {

      // Create the scene and set the scene size.
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
          HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

      // Create a renderer and add it to the DOM.
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
      renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // Create a camera, zoom it out from the model a bit, and add it to the scene.
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 100);
      camera.position.set(0,0.15,3);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
      scene.add(camera);

      // Create an event listener that resizes the renderer with the browser window.
      window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      });

      // Set the background color of the scene.
      renderer.setClearColor(0xd3d3d3, 1);

      // Create a light, set its position, and add it to the scene.
      var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(0,200,100);
      scene.add(light);

      // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
    var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
    loader.load( './models/foot.ply', function ( geometry ) {
            geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            geometry.center();
            var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial           ({ shininess: 1000,vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material           );
            mesh.position.x = 0;
            mesh.position.y = 0;
            mesh.position.z = 0;
            mesh.castShadow = false;
            mesh.receiveShadow = false;
            scene.add( mesh );
    } );

      // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.userPanSpeed = 0.05;

    }


    // Renders the scene and updates the render as needed.
    function animate() {

      // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      // Render the scene.
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      controls.update();

    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: as I don't have separate textures, this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using textures with Three.js and PLY file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109774/using-textures-with-three-js-and-ply-file)

Comment: not a duplicate. this question has nothing to do with textures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `MeshStandardMaterial` use `MeshBasicMaterial`